# Trouble using Google OAuth with Chrome App (CCA)

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, cordova, oauth, google-plus

I am following the guide here:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity#copy_key

Unfortunately, there is no listing for my app in the `~/Library/..../Default/Extensions` folder, or at least no listing that matches the id I see in the `chrome://extensions` page.  I copied the id from that page and used it to make my Client ID in the Google Developers Console but I can't get the following to work:

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, function(token) {
  //...
});
```

It takes me to my chrome settings page and shows me an error asking me to sign in.  If it matters, I am calling the above code from inside an AngularJS controller in a cca-built app (a lot of Google in that stack).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It may not apply to Chrome Apps, but there is a reference Googlel+ Sign-In implementation using AngularJS in the Photohunt sample (https://developers.google.com/+/photohunt) that ships with every server that may lead to alternative approaches to what you're doing in your app.

Comment: @class Hai Gus (it's Sam).  Also I don't think I can use the regular JS Google+ Sign In because in a packaged Chrome app I can't include <script> tags, only offline JS.  Also the issue is just that I'm getting invalid Client ID so I think it's just a matter of how I'm registering my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bit you're missing is that you have to install your extension at least once in order to generate the key.

This: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/key documents the process for generating the key you need.

This: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/identity/manifest.json is an example of what your manifest.json will look like with a properly generated key.

Comment: Thanks, ade, that was it!  I did also get it to work in the meantime by stealing a "key" from one of the example apps on Chrome Github and generating a ClientID that way, but this is obviously better.